# Heroku Procfile. How can I know if it is correct? Error code=H14 desc="No web processes running"

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, gunicorn, procfile

I am very new to coding and I am trying to deploy an app with Heroku. My app works fine with my local host. The app.py file has:

```
from fig import app
if __name__=='__main__':
app = app.run(debug=True)
```

Procfile has:

```
web:gunicorn app.py
```

But every time I try to deploy it I get an error:

```
at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/"   host=procesofig.herokuapp.com request_id=2aacdf80-3a8d-46b6-981c-11464a57c88a fwd="190.42.230.216" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Any idea of what could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

the Procfile in heroku is initiated in a wrong way

use it like this

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

Also make sure to add a requirements.txt with all dependencies

Comment: I changed it but I get the same error. I do have a requirements.txt. Do you know if the procfile should have any other information? Or if I should change my app.py page?